# Angular how to get the component function name after uglify in prod mod

Tags: angular

I do have the following problem, I created a dynamic page which is loading different components by following the [angular documentation tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), the name and the attributes of each component are coming from database.

But the problem is after minification I can't do a proper mapping between the component name: `CoolComponent` and in database I save it as `Cool`.

```
const factories = [CoolComponent, SecondCoolComponent];

const comp = factories.find(f => `{fromDb}Component` === f.name);
const ref = componentRef.createComponent(comp);
```

After the minification `CoolComponent` is transformed in something like `t()` and I do not get any finds.

> Can I get somehow the name of the component after minification and uglyfication in prod mod ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about database.

Comment: You can not. Use a unique attrib and change the behaivour according its value. It's the same problem that when you want to order a table or you use obj[variable], you must make if (variable='name') obj.name="yo" else if (variable='id') obj.id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find any reliable solutions and just used a hack in our componets:

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class CoolComponent {
   static componentName = 'cool';
}

const comp = factories.find(f => dbName === f.componentName);
const ref = componentRef.createComponent(comp);
```